# A php function involving the use of strict comparison with a string in format xx,yy,zz will only execute the code when the condition is not met

Tags: php

I have this function that takes as a parameter a string that is basically numbers concatenated with "," that looks like xx,yy,zz as parameters a "," as $charseparates and a "
"as $charjoins
The function basically recovers the numbers stored in a string and uses them to get certain positions in an array
However that same string received as "$errors" can have a value of "none"
and there is where the problem comes, the code will just act when $errors is not equal to "none"
Have already tried using strcmp and the strict equality but still just the part when $errors is different from "none" will execute properly

The code...
It looks like this

```
function readerrorstring($errors, $charseparates, $charjoins){
  $arrayfaults = array("foo", "more foo", "help  me"....);

  $actualfaults = "";

  if($errors === "none"){
    $actualfaults .= "Parametros en orden";
  }

  if($errors !== "none"){
    $errorsonarray = explode($charseparates, $errors);
    $errorindex = count($errorsonarray);


    for($i = 0; $i<$errorindex; $i++){
       $currentindex = (int)$errorsonarray[$i];
       $currenterror = $arrayfaults[$currentindex];
       $actualfaults = $actualfaults.$currenterror.$charjoins;
    }

  }

  return $actualfaults;
}
```

Hope it won't bother

Comment: I don't quite get what the problem is? What exactly is your input? What output do you get? And what do you expect to get?

Comment: Sorry
Well
The output if the input looks like this:
"44,55,66"
Would be like
"Thing in position 44"
"thing in position 55"
"thing in position 66"

if $errors = "none"
my output would be "There is nothing in the array that matches this, you are ok"

the problem is that before getting those messages I compare with an if($errors === "none"){code}
else{}
only the code in the else would execute even if $errors === "none"
in fact when $errors === "none" I get a blank screen

Comment: Then if `$errros` is equal `none`, do `var_dump($errors);` right before the if statement and tell us what you get.

Comment: The 6 means that there are two characters left...
I think I am getting an idea from the origin of the error

Comment: *string(**6**) "none "* <- Do you see 6 characters there? You probably have some spaces or other characters in there. Try to use `trim()` before you're comparing.

Comment: Lesson learned: Use the debug functions [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)/[`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to see what you actually have inside a variable :)